# performSelectorOnMainThread called too early

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage, performselector

XCode 4.5.2; I'm downloading an image from a remote server like this :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];
NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]
                                    initWithTarget:self
                                    selector:@selector(loadImage)
                                    object:nil];

[queue addOperation:operation];
}

- (void)loadImage{
self.theobject = [RemoteQuery loadObjectWithImage:self.imageKey];

[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(displayImage) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}

-(void)displayImage{
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: self.theobject.imageData];
[self.imageView setImage:image];

}
```

This works fine on IOS simulator, but doesn't work on a device; it seems like displayImage is called before the data is loaded from [RemoteQuery loadImage].  What would be the best way to ensure that the image has loaded properly before showing it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a delegate protocol which will call back to the original object when the image download finishes. This [NSOperation tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues) has more details on how to do this

Alternatively, use the `NSOperation`'s `completionBlock` to perform the image display.